# red jam like gum seeping from ivy

Tags: english-ivy

dark red colored jam like gum substance is seeping out from a  very small (stem) patch of english ivy. what is that, and what I need to do?

Comment: Can you add a photo showing that problem please

Comment: Can you add a picture? That would help us better understand the problem